# Missing bean in repository

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, applicationcontext

My application fails to start because spring can't see bean.

I'm trying to run mu application and add created user to db. I have no idea how to create missing bean. I found that there must be annotation @Repository above interface, so I placed it, but it still doesn't work.

User:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable, UserInterface {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8062231146287834334L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column
private String login;
@Column
private String password;
@Column
private String email;
@Column
private Long phoneNumber;
@Column
private String firstName;
@Column
private String lastName;
@Column
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
@Column
private String address;
@Column
private String city;
@Column
private String zipCode;

public User() {
    //constructor for hibernate
}

private User(String login, String password, String email, Long     phoneNumber, String firstName,
             String lastName, LocalDate dateOfBirth, String address,     String city, String zipCode) {

    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

@Override
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public Long getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

@Override
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Override
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Override
public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

@Override
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

@Override
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

@Override
public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "login='" + login + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
            ", address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", zipCode='" + zipCode + '\'' +
            '}';
}
public static class UserBuilder {

    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Long phoneNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String zipCode;

    public UserBuilder setUserLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserPhoneNumber(Long phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = LocalDate.parse(dateOfBirth);
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder setUserZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        return this;
    }

    public User build() {
        boolean isAllFielsdAreFull = login != null && password != null && email != null
                && phoneNumber != null && firstName != null
                && lastName != null && dateOfBirth != null && address != null
                && city != null && zipCode != null;

        if (isAllFielsdAreFull) {
            return new User(login, password, email, phoneNumber, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, address, city, zipCode);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Some fields are null!");
        }
    }

}

}
```

UserRepo:

```
package wawer.kamil.library;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import wawer.kamil.library.domain.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Controller:

```
package wawer.kamil.library;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import wawer.kamil.library.domain.User;

@Controller 
public class Start {

private UserRepo userRepo;

@Autowired
public Start(UserRepo userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
}

@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void run() {
    User user = new User.UserBuilder()
            .setUserLogin("Mareczek")
            .setUserPassword("Mareczek3@")
            .setUserEmail("mareczek@gmail.com")
            .setUserPhoneNumber(515791468L)
            .setUserFirstName("Marek")
            .setUserLastName("Kowalski")
            .setUserDateOfBirth("1990-12-12")
            .setUserAddress("Kowalska 12")
            .setUserCity("Lublin")
            .setUserZipCode("20-123")
            .build();

    userRepo.save(user);

}
}


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:32768/library
?serverTimezone=Europe/Warsaw
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Main class:

```
package wawer.kamil.library;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LibraryApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Error Logs:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run     your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-10 11:19:30.771 ERROR 6282 --- [           main]     o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in wawer.kamil.library.Start required a bean of type 'wawer.kamil.library.UserRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'wawer.kamil.library.UserRepo' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would like to run my application, and add user to db.

Comment: can you please show the error logs ? can you also post the screenshot of your project structure ?

Comment: sure, i forgot. Updated!

Comment: Show your Main class with `@SpringBootApplication`  - with package name.

Comment: I added, but this classic start class

Comment: Add `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"RepositoryPackage"})` under `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: In what package is is `UserRepo` defined ?

Comment: @michalk package wawer.kamil.library;

Comment: Place it under package that is below `wawer.kamil.library` package.

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha, I added but I receive the same logs... ;/

Comment: @KamilWawer have you tried this `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"wawer.kamil.library.UserRepo"})` under `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha I additionally pasted package path above my classes. I changed annotation to "@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"wawer.kamil.library"})", but unfortunately, it still doesn't work - the same logs.

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha: I also found missed extra log : Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)Maybe it is some problem with the constructor (especially field ID)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable repositories

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories // this will fix the issue
public class LibraryApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LibraryApplication.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem. The same logs :(